# Is it possible to have a positive exponential function that starts below zero?

Tags: exponential-function

I'm working on a project for my math class. We need to make an image on our calculators (Texas Instruments) using the `DrawF` function (which graphs functions as `y=`). I need an exponential function that starts *below zero*. From what I understand, they can't (according to my Algebra II textbook and a few Google searches).

Is it possible to draw the line I need with an exponential?

*Side note: I would rather use this than, say, mushing it together with other types of equations because we need at least two exponential functions, and I can't find a better place to use them.*

Comment: You mean like $e^x-1$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiplying an exponential function by any real number is still an exponential function

Take $$f(x) = -e^{x}$$

Then $f(0) = -1$.  On the other hand if you want purely a function which is of the form $f(x) = a^x$, you will need to use complex numbers but then there's no real concept of a number being "negative"

Comment: I'm not quite sure I understand this answer. From what I understand, it's not possible for me to do this without complex numbers?

Comment: I'm saying it depends on what exactly you want.  You need to be clear about how you're defining an exponential so that we can give you an exact answer

Comment: Thanks! I think I got my answer.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible. Shift it so that the start point is below the x-axis. Or are you asking whether the an unshifted function is possible?
Note: If the function is not shifted below the y-axis (by adding a negative constant), no such function can exist in the real plane. Complex equations of this type can exist.